# Can Shorewall be used on VyOS?

Tags: networking, configuration, firewall, vyos, shorewall

Will VyOS still work right if I install Shorewall-lite on it?  Shorewall seems like an easier way to setup a network, but VyOS seems pretty great for day-to-day management of a router / firewall.  So I was wondering if they are compatible.  From what I understand about Shorewall, it just generates a bunch of iptables rules, and VyOS is a Linux dirstro with iptables, so it seems to me that it should work, but I thought I would just check if there were any other caveats about why they are not compatible that I should know about before putting the research into setting something like this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorewall-lite is a very light weight tool to manage a firewall configuration generated on another server.  It is not suitable for setting up the configuration, but does manage the generated configuration.  It runs quite well on OpenWRT, which is a distribution intended for routers.

The current version of Shorewall is Perl based.  This can make the installation much larger than you would want for a router.

Of the tools I have used, I find Shorewall the easiest to use.  There are example configuration which generally require little modification.  I have done fairly complex configuration for a smaller network quite easily.

Comment: So it could be used, but it will make the size of your installation a bit bigger than you intended?

Comment: @leeand00  Shorewall-lite is extremely lean. But you need another server to build the ruleset on. Shorewall is less lean, but it is perl that will take the most space.  If you already have perl, Shorewall is a fairly small install.

Comment: yes I was planning on using a separate workstation to deploy the Shorewall configuration to Shorewall-lite on the VyOS router.